# Installing PHP and MySQL as a service in Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux, service, installation

As a PHP developer, I have been using Xampp for running PHP and MySQL in my computer. I use its GUI, install it, and then set PHP and MySQL to run as a service when the Windows is loading. Now, I need to do the same in Linux (Like Ubuntu).
How can I install PHP and MySQL as a service in Linux? Is there any GUI for Linux too ?

Comment: I guess http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for your question.

Comment: Take a look at the available tags in Stackoverflow.com and then you can make sure that I can ask this question here too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php5
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: Won't the last apt-get install the rest as dependancies? And restart the server as a post-install script?

Comment: i was not sure, but its safe if it does, and if it doesn't you are already covered.

Comment: Could you tell me how you can install them as a service? I want use them without any manual starting attempt.

Comment: no such thing in *nix, you should read up on some basics first.

Comment: They are most likely installed as "services" when you install the package.

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good guide over at [how to forge](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server)